# python code loop is not iterating as per the requirement

Tags: python

I'm trying to iterate the values in a specific format from a json file, but it seems that the loop got broken after during the iteration process.

My sample  python code is

```
import json
import re
from pprint import pprint

fields = {}
out = []

with open('test.json', 'r') as f:
    msg = json.load(f)

    for segments in msg["parsedData"]["segments"]:
        if "PID" in segments["segmentId"]:
            seg = segments["fields"]
            for i in seg.keys():
                f = re.search(r"([0-9]+)\[", i)
                index = re.search(r"\[([0-9]+)\]", i)
                l = re.search(r"\]([0-9.]+)", i)
                if f is not None and index is not None and l is not None:
                    f = f.group(1)
                    i = index.group(1)
                    l = l.group(1)

                    fields[ f + l ] = {}
                    for x in filter(lambda x: x.startswith(f"{f}[{i}]{l}"), seg.keys()):
                        fields[ f + l ][ i ] = seg[ x ]

pprint(fields)
```

My json file(test.json)

```
{  "parsedData": {
      "segments": [
        {
          "segmentId": "PID",
          "fields": {
            "5.1": "EGHFG",
            "7": "19680808",
            "3[0].1": "working1",
            "3[1].1": "working2",
            "3[1].5": "test2",
            "5.2": "DFSHY",
            "18": "280156074",
            "3[1].4": "WR",
            "3[0].5": "test1",
            "4[0].5": "HAI",
            "0": "PID"
                   }
                 }
      ]
         }
}
```

I'm trying print the output like below

```
{'3.1': {'0':'working1','1':'working2'},
'3.4': {'1': 'WR'},
'3.5': {'0': 'test1','1': 'test2'},
'4.5': {'0': 'EPI'}}
```

Anyone has any idea to sort out this code and please correct me if I did anything wrong.

Awaiting for your kind response.

Comment: Which loop isn't working?

Comment: Can you elaborate on *"the loop got broken"*?  Do you get an error message or any other output?

Comment: Why do you need 3 regexp? `m = re.search(r"(\d+)\[(\d+)\]([\d.]+), i)` will find all the pieces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that this line:

```
fields[ f + l ] = {}
```

reinitializes `fields[f+l]`, so you lose the values that were assigned on a previous iteration.

You can change that to check whether the element already exists:

```
if f+l not in fields:
    fields[ f + l ] = {}
```

or you can use `defaultdict`:

```
field = defaultdict(dict)
```

```
import re
from pprint import pprint
from collections import defaultdict

msg = {
    "parsedData": {
        "segments": [
            {
                "segmentId": "PID",
                "fields": {
                    "5.1": "EGHFG",
                    "7": "19680808",
                    "3[0].1": "working1",
                    "3[1].1": "working2",
                    "3[1].5": "test2",
                    "5.2": "DFSHY",
                    "18": "280156074",
                    "3[1].4": "WR",
                    "3[0].5": "test1",
                    "4[0].5": "HAI",
                    "0": "PID"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }

fields = defaultdict(dict)

for segments in msg["parsedData"]["segments"]:
    if "PID" in segments["segmentId"]:
        seg = segments["fields"]
        for i in seg.keys():
            f = re.search(r"([0-9]+)\[", i)
            index = re.search(r"\[([0-9]+)\]", i)
            l = re.search(r"\]([0-9.]+)", i)
            if f is not None and index is not None and l is not None:
                f = f.group(1)
                i = index.group(1)
                l = l.group(1)

                for x in filter(lambda x: x.startswith(f"{f}[{i}]{l}"), seg.keys()):
                    fields[ f + l ][ i ] = seg[ x ]

pprint(dict(fields))
```

BTW, `x.startswith(f"{f}[{i}]{l}")` seems like a poor check. If you have keys `3[0]1` and `3[0]10`, you'll match the latter key when you're looking for the former.

Answer (score 0):

Only one regex is enough to capture the 3 parts, and a `defautdict` is very useful to avoid the need of filling empty keys

```
import re
from collections import defaultdict

fields = defaultdict(dict)
for segments in msg["parsedData"]["segments"]:
    if "PID" in segments["segmentId"]:
        for key, val in segments["fields"].items():
            m = re.search(r"(\d+)\[(\d+)]([\d.]+)", key)
            if m:
                a, b, c = m.groups()
                fields[a + c][b] = val
```